# AS3- Reading the first element from XML

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I loaded XML in AS3. 
In that XML, I make that flash will retrieving a value of an attribute and traced it.
the output was:

```
test1,test2,test3,test4
```

But I want that flash will output only the first element from that output (test1 only). I searched in Google and I didn't find an answer.

Sample of my XML content :

```
<data>
    <myXML typesId="test1,test2,test3,test4"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Could you show your XML content (an example) ?

Comment: yes:
<data>
<myXML typesId="test1,test2,test3,test4"/>
</data>

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the first word (`test1`) from the `typesId` parameter using `String.substr()` function :

```
var xml:XML = <data>
    <myXML typesId="test1,test2,test3,test4"/>
</data>;

var types:String = xml.myXML.@typesId;

trace(types.substr(0, types.indexOf(',')));     // gives : test1
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! its fixed my problem :)

Comment: @Motimot You are welcome. If my answer was what you are looking for, you can select it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with Regular Expression:

```
var data:XML =
<data>
    <myXML typesId="test1,test2,test3,test4"/>
</data>;

var word:String = data.myXML.@typesId.toString().replace(/^([^,]+).*$/, "$1");
```

The value of the word will be `test1`.